# Selective deletions from a list

Tags: list-manipulation, sequence

i have two lists of strings with unequal numbers of subelements in each.

i would like to remove from lis2 all instances where a pattern in lis1 appears in lis2:

```
lis1 = {{"a","b","c","d"}, {"w","x","y","z"}}

lis2 = {{"q","a","b","c","d","r"},{"j","k","l","m","n","o"}}
```

to give:

```
res = {"j","k","l","m","n","o"}
```

Thanks for ideas.

Addendum:  Thanks for your replies!

I can't seem to make any of the suggestions work with the following lists:

```
lis1 = {{"a", "19", "b", "29"}, {"c", "42", "d", "13"}, {"e", "42", "f","10"}, {"g", "13", "h", "23"}, {"i", "14", "j", "26"}, {"k", "14", "l", "34"}, {"m", "7", "n", "77"}}
```

and

```
lis2 = {{DateObject[{2022, 9, 3}, "Day"], "w", "17", "x", "48", "AWAY", False}, {DateObject[{2022, 9, 3}, "Day"], "y", "0", "z", "55","AWAY", True}, {DateObject[{2022, 9, 3}, "Day"], "g", "13", "h","23", "AWAY", True}, {DateObject[{2022, 9, 3}, "Day"], "o", "13","p", "21", "AWAY", True}, {DateObject[{2022, 9, 3}, "Day"], "q","14", "r", "28", "AWAY", True}, {DateObject[{2022, 9, 3}, "Day"],"s", "1", "t", "2", "AWAY", True}}
```

The desired result is:

```
{{DateObject[{2022, 9, 3}, "Day"], "w", "17","x","48","AWAY", False}, {DateObject[{2022, 9, 3}, "Day"], "y", "0","z","55", "AWAY", True}, {DateObject[{2022, 9, 3}, "Day"], "o", "13", "p", "21", "AWAY", True}, {DateObject[{2022, 9, 3}, "Day"], "q", "14", "r", "28", "AWAY", True}, {DateObject[{2022, 9, 3}, "Day"], "s", "1", "t", "2", "AWAY", True}}
```

...in which the element containing the pattern {"g","13","h","23"} from lis1 is deleted from lis2.

Comment: Try: `Cases[lis2, Except[{___, PatternSequence["a", "b", "c", "d"], ___}]]`

Comment: **Post-addendum:** The pattern `{"g","13","h","23"}` is deleted from `lis2` because it is present in `lis1`. If you want to check for a complete signature match over a number of fields in `lis2` then this could be another question. Right now any sub-sequence will result in a match, which is kind of limiting. In that case, I think the addendum can be posted as a new question.

Comment: Thank you.  Will do.

Comment: try `DeleteCases[Alternatives @@ ({_, ##, ___} & @@@ lis1)] @ lis2`?

Comment: Yes kglr that works, thank you so much!

Answer (score 7):

> pattern in lis1 appears in lis2

You mean if the intersection between any subsets is zero, you keep it? So even if one letter shows up between the two sets, then this is a hit, right? so you scan lis2, checking if any subset has no intersection with any of the sublists in lis1.

How about

```
lis1 = {{"a", "b", "c", "d"}, {"w", "x", "y", "z"}}
lis2 = {{"q", "a", "b", "c", "d", "r"}, {"j", "k", "l", "m", "n", 
   "o"}, {"a"}, {"w", "x"}, {"h", "v"}}
Cases[lis2, x_ /; Length[Flatten[Intersection[x, #] & /@ lis1]] == 0]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For your example

```
lis1 = {{"a", "b", "c", "d"}, {"w", "x", "y", "z"}}
lis2 = {{"q", "a", "b", "c", "d", "r"}, {"j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o"}}
Cases[lis2, x_ /; Length[Flatten[Intersection[x, #] & /@ lis1]] == 0]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

There are many other ways to do this in Mathematica. At least 9 more ways I would say.

Answer (score 6):

Using @Nasser's example data:

```
lis1 = {{"a", "b", "c", "d"}, {"w", "x", "y", "z"}}
lis2 = {{"q", "a", "b", "c", "d", "r"}, {"j", "k", "l", "m", "n", 
   "o"}, {"a"}, {"w", "x"}, {"h", "v"}}

Extract[lis2
 , Position[
  LongestCommonSubsequence[#, Catenate@lis1] & /@ lis2
  , {}
  ]
 ]
```

> {{"j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o"}, {"h", "v"}}

Answer (score 5):

Using `ContainsAll` and the `If` statement:

```
Map[If[ContainsAll[#, Intersection[Flatten@lis1, Flatten@lis2]] === True, Nothing, #] &, lis2]
(*{{"j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o"}}*)
```

Or, using `ContainsAny` and the `If` statement:

```
Map[If[ContainsAny[#, Intersection[Flatten@lis1, Flatten@lis2]] === True, Nothing, #] &, lis2]
(*{{"j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o"}}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a = 
 {{"a", "b", "c", "d"}, {"w", "x", "y", "z"}};

b = 
 {{"q", "a", "b", "c", "d", "r"}, {"j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o"}, 
  {"a"}, {"w", "x"}, {"h", "v"}};
```

Using `SequenceAlignment`

```
Pick[b, FreeQ[Alternatives @@ a] @ SequenceAlignment[#, Flatten @ a] & /@ b]
```

> {{"j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o"}, {"a"}, {"h", "v"}}

The above also shows the `{"a"}`. If this is not wanted:

```
Cases[{_, __}] @ %
```

> {{"j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o"}, {"h", "v"}}